# Using JQuery to hide <li> element of main menu based on its class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, hide

On a wordpress website, I am using the following code inside the head section of `header.php` to check if users are logged in (not in wordpress admin but a separate login area) and if they are not, I would like to hide a specific menu item (using the `li` element's class name with JQuery):

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["username"])) {  

    // Do all relevant code for logged in users here

    }

else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#menu-main-navigation-1 li.menu-item-123').hide();        


 });      

</script>
<?php
    // Do all relevant code for logged-out users here  

    }
?>
```

The `ul` element's id is `menu-main-navigation-1` and the class of the `li` that needs to be hidden is `menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-123`

I have tried both with `$(document).ready(function()` and without but it didn't make any difference, the menu item still shows up.

Comment: can you try to use a delay to check if it works? `setTimeout(function(){ ... // your code here to hide }, 500);`

Comment: Is jQuery definitely loaded on the page? And is it before the script you're inserting? Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but didn't work. jQuery is definitely loaded on the page without errors on the console. Is there a way to do this with php code only instead ?

Comment: @Michal - in that case try printing out the value of the cookie, perhaps it isn't doing what you expect (and in particular is set when the user isn't logged in)?

Comment: And in theory you can do this in PHP, by putting an `if` block around whatever PHP code generates that list item. I'm not familiar with the internals of WordPress so I don't know where that would be.

Comment: Go into console, and select the `ul` element and copy/paste to your question. If that `ul` element is MASSIVE, maybe just copy the `ul` open tag portion, then skim down to the `li` in question and copy it only. However it would be best if you included the whole thing... for id/class clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `hide` is not a very good idea. It only changes the item's visibility but it will be still present in the source. If you **absolutely** have to do it in javascript, call `remove`, but this method still doesn't account for those users who have it disabled.

But fortunately, you can remove elements from the wordpress menu by hooking before the html generation:

```
 function filter_remove_menu_item_for_anons($menu_items, $args) {
    foreach($menu_items as $k => $item) {
      if ($item->ID == 123) {
        unset($menu_items[$k]);
      }
    }
    return $menu_items;
  }
  add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'filter_remove_menu_item_for_anons', 10, 2);
```

Just register the filter based on your session checks.

If you have several menus and need finer control, you can do additional checks with the [args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) parameter.

However, if the user knows the URL, he will still be able to access the content, and you should consider other [solution](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach ... you can also use CSS to hide the list item - which is probably better.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE["username"])) {

  } else {
?>

   <style>
      #menu-main-navigation-1 li.menu-item-123 { display: none !important; }
   </style>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Note: if they disable CSS, the list will show up. The original approach, if you disable JavaScript... same thing.